# On demand color set of rows in SmartClient (TreeGrid)

Tags: smartclient

I have a TreeGrid in SmartClient. Now I want to color some set of lines like line numbers 3-5, 7-11 etc. I am using an external button which passes the values to the SmartClient. Can anybody tell me how to do that? A button is passing the value and it's working fine. But the problem is, where to get the value in SmartClient and how can I color that set of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TreeGrid is a ListGrid, I would imagine you could override the getCellStyle function and set the colors as you see necessary.

http://www.smartclient.com/docs/8.1/a/b/c/go.html#search=getcellstyle

So basically in pseudo code:

```
if (row >= 3 and row <=5)
     return "style1"
if (row >= 7 and row <=11)
     return "style2"
else
     return this.baseStyle
```

where style1 and 2 are defined in css

Comment: Thanks, I and selecting starting and end row number through buttons. can you tell me how to do it. I have prev and next button, and I want auto refresh also.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but I suggest looking at the CSS stylesheet and seeing how they deal with selected rows.  You could easily override any of the other functions of a ListGrid like setSelected() just as you would with the getCellStyle() function above.

Answer (score 0):

And how to custom and keep states with using specific style name (myStyle) like :

- myStyle
- myStyleDark
- myStyleOver
- myStyleOverDark
- myStyleSelected
- myStyleSelectedDark
- myStyleSelectedOver
- myStyleSelectedOverDark
- myStyleDisabled
- myStyleDisabledDark

I try to use @Override of getCellStyle
for returning "myStyleA" or "myStyleB"
which i want conserve dynamics suffixs : "Dark", "Over", "Selected", ...

An idea ?...

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html

```
The state of the record is indicated by adding a suffix to the base style.
There are four independent boolean states, which are combined in the order given:

"Disabled" : whether the cell is disabled; enable by setting the "enabled" flag on record returned by getCellRecord
"Selected" : whether cell is selected; enable by passing a Selection object as "selection"
"Over" : mouse is over this cell; enable with showRollovers
"Dark" : alternating color bands; enable with alternateRowStyles
```